# sum variable Σ Xik = Σ Xkj for i=j=k=1…N, in one constraint with choco

Tags: java, choco

I am using choco to solve a CSP , and one of my constraints is that the sum of one variables Σ Xik = Σ Xkj for i=j=k=1…N. 
How do I accomplish this? thank you for your help.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Please read the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) article "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"

Comment: in other words model.sum does not allow to model two constraints as I did. So the question is what is another way of doing it

Comment: **Edit** the question and clarify it.

Comment: I formulated my question I hope it is clearer